# Time to Put or Call a Bond

Tags: bond, risk-management, put-call-parity

I was studying putable bond and callable bond on my own, there is an exercise question that was a little confusing to me: [image]

I understand what the answer explains, but I am confused that, is a bond "that is putable at t=4" equal to a 4-year bond that is putable? Statement 1 says, (1) is a bond putable at t=4, I thought it meant the bond can only be put at or after t=4. Statement (2) is a 4 year bond that is callable. According to the answer, with put-call parity, the value of the bond in statement (2) is equal to that of a 4 year bond that is putable. However, does that mean the bond can be put any time within 4 years?

If so, how can the value of statement (1) and (2) be the same? Or is it that the time to put the bond does not matter when valuing a bond?

Answer (score 3):

Aren’t both statements incorrect?  In a puttable bond, the investor is LONG the put.  In a callable bond , the investor is SHORT the call.  It may be true that put price = call price for ATM options, but being long a put is always better than being short a call.

Comment: Thank you I will double check with the publisher.

Comment: Ask the publisher for a refund...